# ¿Cuál sería el algoritmo para mostrar una imagen con una fecha inicial y una fecha fin?

Tags: laravel, date

Por ejemplo:
Un proyecto tiene una fecha inicial y una fecha final, este mismo contiene una imagen, si las fechas no han finalizado se muestra la imagen, sino no debe mostrar la imagen.
Laravel tiene algún metodo más rápido?

Comment: Nos mostrarías por favor lo que llevas, considera que Laravel tiene a Carbon para el manejo de fechas, lo cual lo hace muy simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrías usar *PHP* nativo dentro de *laravel* ya que no es tan complicado, la alternativa seria *Carbon* pero yo lo haria asi dentro de la función de chequeo...

```
<?php
$fecha_inicial= '2019-10-01';

$fecha_final = '2019-10-25';

$fecha_actual = date('Y-m-d');



  $inicial = strtotime($fecha_inicial);
  $final = strtotime($fecha_final);
  $actual = strtotime($fecha_actual);

  if($actual >= $inicial && $actual<=$final){
    $imagen = ""; //enviar la variable imagen...
  }else{
    $imagen = "default_imagen.jpg"; //enviar imagen por defecto o sin imagen...
  }
?>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias enserio me ha servido de mucho y ha solucionado el problema.